# Uso de interfaz en Java

Tags: java

Tengo un cuadro de texto (`JTextField`) y quiero que un botón (`botonIniciar`) se active o desactive en función de dicho cuadro de texto (`cuadroUserName`). En otras palabras, si el cuadro de texto tiene texto (valga la redundancia) el botón se active, pero si no tiene el botón se encuentre apagado.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Este es mi código:

```
//CUADRO DE TEXTO
cuadroUserName = new JTextField();
cuadroUserName.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
cuadroUserName.setText("");       
cuadroUserName.setBounds(220, 50, 152, 20);
contentPane.add(cuadroUserName);
cuadroUserName.setColumns(10);

//BOTON
JButton botonIniciar = new JButton("Aceptar nombre");
botonIniciar.setBounds(100, 85, 125, 23);
contentPane.add(botonIniciar);
botonIniciar.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Hola, recuerda agregar lo que intentaste por favor, revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: No lo añadí porque no se como hacerlo

Comment: Hay que demostrar investigaciòn, el sitio no esta destinado para realizar tareas si no ayudar a solucionar a partir de un problema en la implementaciòn. saludos

Comment: Pues estoy pidiendo ayuda en la implementación. No estoy pidiendo que alguien lo haga, si no que me digan como hacerlo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

holas, puedes ponerle un keyListener al `JTextField` asi:

```
cuadroUserName.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                          
        if(evt.getSource() == cuadroUserName){
        
            String texto = cuadroUserName.getText();
        
            if (texto.equals("")){
                botonIniciar.setEnabled(false);
            } else { 
                botonIniciar.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }  
    }
});
```

eso lo que hace es que, cuando tu sueltas una tecla dentro del `JTextField`, guarda el texto que hayas ingresado en la variable `texto` y luego comprueba si la variable tiene texto o no, si tiene texto, el botón se activa, y si no tiene el botón se desactiva.